# Trying to access Parent and then the sibling element in selenium. Throws no element exception

Tags: selenium, xpath

Element structure

```
//table[@class='table-table-condensed']//tbody//tr...
  <td class="ng-binding">TEXT1</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">2020-04-17 18:55:58.022</td>
  <td>
    <span class="label label-default">Not Started</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="pull-right">
      <button class="btn-success"/>
      <button class="run"/>
      <button class="review"/>
    </div>
  </td>
```

Trying to access the button element :

If Text Matches for this Element :

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement.By(xpath("//table[@class='table-table-condensed']//tbody//tr//td[@class='ng-binding'][1]");
String str = we.text();
if(str.equals("TEXT1"))
{
    WebElement ex = we.findElement(By.xpath("./parent::following:://button[@class='run']"));

    ex.click();
}
```

this throws no element found exception, Tried `following::sibling` too. Can we use both the tags at a time here. How to access the button element.

Also, will `following::` tag does not work, if I had to access the below tags in structure:

```
<td class ="ng-binding">2020-04-17 18:55:58.022</td>   ( Need to extract this element to sort the list by Latest date)

AND

<span class ="label label-default">Not Started</span>
```

Comment: Can you please share your url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `./parent::following:://button[@class='run']` is not valid XPath!

The correct form is: `axis::node[predicate]`. You are not allowed to chain multiple axis together, **and** you must specify a node! Note that a wilcard `*` node is still valid.

What you are probably looking for is `./following-sibling::td//button[@class='run']` or possibly `./following::button[@class='run']`.

Answer (score 2):

Try below solution

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)    
elementText= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table-table-condensed']//tbody//tr/following-sibling::td[contains(text(),'Test1')][contains(@id, "ng-binding")]")))
button=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='run']")))
if(elementText.text=="Test1"): 
   button.click()
else:
   print "Not found!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Other approach, you can try to solve this by using `tr[contains(., 'TEXT VALUE')]`:

```
String text = "TEXT1";
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table-table-condensed']//tr[contains(., '" +text +"')]//td[2]"));
WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table-table-condensed']//tr[contains(., '" +text +"')]//span"));
WebElement element3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table-table-condensed']//tr[contains(., '" +text +"')]//button[@class='run']"));
System.out.println(element1.getText());
System.out.println(element2.getText());
element3.click();
```

Comment: this works if there is only single row, I ahve multiple rows here.